# How to place the scrollbar to a jquery ui tab within a jquery ui modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a simple modal dialog window. Inside the window, I have created two tabs. Within tabs, I have put a dynamic tree. The dynamic tree can grow in size when clicked on. When this happens, I get a scrollbar, on the side of the modal dialog window.

The problem is when I scroll down, the tab titles within my dialog disappear. Is there a way to make sure the tab titles are stationary ? In other words, rather than make the dialog bar scrollable, can the tabs have a scrollbar ?

I am quite green on css and javascript. The tabs are displayed within this modal dialog. From that point on, dialog becomes scrollable when the tree is expanded instead of the tabs.

```
<div id="dialog" title="File Browser">
    <div id="tabs">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#finance">Finance FileShare</a></li>
         <li><a href="#hr">HR Fileshare</a></li>
       </ul>
     <div id="finance">
          <div id="financetree"></div>
     </div>
     <div id="hr">
            <div id="hrtree"></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div>Active node: <span id="echoActive">-</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: any links or sample code to what you're doing?

Comment: There definitely is, basically you need to add an extra wrapper and change the css overflow settings on it.  If you could, I'd recommend creating a jsfiddle and posting that up, as it'd greatly help you to get a better reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin will add a class `.ui-tabs-panel` to your panels, in your case the elements `#finance` and `#hr`.

The following CSS will fix the height of those panels and add a vertical scrollbar:

```
.ui-tabs-panel {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto; // show vertical scroll if necessary
    overflow-x: hidden; // hide horizontal scroll
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Y4NkS/)**

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I tried using the overflow: auto on the tab divs but for some reason, I could not get it to work.

Comment: Why do I not see a scrollbar if I donot put a height attribute ? Even specifying percentages does not seem to help, I need to put in a specific set of pixels.

Comment: If you don't set the height explicitly, the container will expand to show all the content, this is the default flow behavior. Now if you put a percentage, 30% for instance, remember this: 30% of what ? 30% of the parent's height obviously, so your parent should have a height defined then.

Comment: Thanks. Reading your explanation affirmed me that I was on the right track and got it resolved using percentage rather than pixels. They do not seem to like specifying the pixels and want to stick with percentage.